# Calculate the distance covered by a balloon in 10seconds

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics

**Here's my problem:**
A balloon starts to move upward from rest with acceleration. The balloon has mass of 500 kg and volume of 600 cubic meters.

I am prompted to find out distance covered by the balloon in 10 seconds. (Consider density of air is constant)

I've tried to calculate the acceleration with Newton's 2nd law. Then I was going to use kinematics.

Consider downwards as the positive direction. Then, 
$$mg-\rho gV = -ma $$
I can easily get $\rho$ from $\rho=m/V$

The problem for me is that when I calculate, I get that $mg$ and $\rho gV$ is equal. Then $-ma$ becomes 0 and I'm not sure how the balloon is moving with acceleration, as stated in the problem description.

I would like to get help if I am accurately plugging in some of the variables in the F.net=ma equation. Is there other things I have to use in this problem? Maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing that in the equation $F_{bouyant} = \rho V g$, $\rho$ is the density of the medium(outside air in this case). What you have taken is the density of the balloon. The density of air must be given in the question.